# Send dynamic html file on mail

Tags: html, django, email, django-templates

I tried sending html on mail using `django-mailgun` but it sends whole HTML contain rather than just rendered HTML table. What I want, is to send rendered table on mail.

Here is my code:

```
def send_email():
  dict = [....]        #it contains list of data that I want to render 
  html_message = render_to_string('email.html', {'data': dict})
  msg = EmailMessage('Hello', html_message,'mailgun@sandboxccd9ae5xxx6486546476d879gd.mailgun.org', ['abc@gmail.com'])
  msg.content_subtype = "html"  
  msg.send()
```

Here's my HTML table:

```
  <table style=" border:1px solid black; border-top:1px solid transparent; border-left:1px solid transparent; border-right:1px solid transparent; width:80%;  border-collapse: collapse; font-size:95%; margin-left:10%; margin-right:10%; margin-top:5%; ">
    <thead>
        <tr><th colspan=5  style=" border-bottom:1px solid black; border-right:none; border-left:none; text-align:center; padding:4x"><h4>Activity List</h4></th></tr>
        <tr style="border:1px solid black">
            <th style="border:1px solid black">col 1</th>
            <th style="border:1px solid black">col 2</th>
            <th style="border:1px solid black">col 3</th>
            <th style="border:1px solid black">col 4</th>
            <th style="border:1px solid black">col 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <body>
        {% for item in data %}
        <tr>
            <td style="border:1px solid; text-align:right; padding: 4px">{{ item.data1 }}</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid; text-align:right; padding: 4px">{{ item.data2 }}</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid; text-align:right; padding: 4px">{{ item.data3 }}</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid; text-align:right; padding: 4px">{{ item.data4 }}</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid; text-align:right; padding: 4px">{{ item.data5 }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
```

I am getting this on my mail:

```
<table style=" border:1px solid black; border-top:1px solid transparent; border-left:1px solid transparent; border-right:1px solid transparent; width:80%;  border-collapse: collapse; font-size:95%; margin-left:10%; margin-right:10%; margin-top:5%; ">
    <thead>
        <tr><th colspan=5  style=" border-bottom:1px solid black; border-right:none; border-left:none; text-align:center; padding:4x"><h4>Activity List</h4></th></tr>
        <tr style="border:1px solid black">
            <th style="border:1px solid black">col 1</th>
            <th style="border:1px solid black">col 2</th>
            <th style="border:1px solid black">col 3</th>
            <th style="border:1px solid black">col 4</th>
            <th style="border:1px solid black">col 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td style="border:1px solid; text-align:right; padding: 4px">data 11</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid; text-align:right; padding: 4px">data 12</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid; text-align:right; padding: 4px">data 13</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid; text-align:right; padding: 4px">data 14</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid; text-align:right; padding: 4px">data 15</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="border:1px solid; text-align:right; padding: 4px">data 21</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid; text-align:right; padding: 4px">data 22</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid; text-align:right; padding: 4px">data 23</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid; text-align:right; padding: 4px">data 24</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid; text-align:right; padding: 4px">data 25</td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: `dict = [...]` Isn't that a list? That should be a dictionary like `dict = {...}`.

Comment: No, I m using a list of item that I fetch from database and  I don't think it's important over here. Please try to stick to the context of my question. If you dont  have any solution to my  problem then don't write any unnecessary comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Django’s email library, you can do this using the EmailMultiAlternatives class.

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

It worked for me. Try this.
Refer:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types